# Having issues while running Robot framework script for safari

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, safari, robotframework

Having issues while running Robot framework script for safari. Error Message is:

> WebDriverException: Message: The command 'GET
>   /session/449F1E1C-C1FF-46BD-B524-32B440D42DCF/element/node-14E1BC51-1DC3-4BEC-9421-F58450DD7752/displayed'
>   was not found.

Comment: show your code if possible

Comment: In addition to a good example of your code can you also describe the circumstances under which you are running your code? For example which versions of Robot Framework, Python, Selenium and Selenium Library you're using as well as WebDriver and browser version.